# How to find a wrong predictor value based on other correlated predictors

Tags: outliers, leverage

I have five correlated predictors, ref the following pairs plot:

[image: Pairs plot]

Now I suspect that sometimes a predictor is wrong, as these come from different sources. In other words, four of the predictors of an observation can be right, but the fifth predictor can still be wrong. How can I detect this?

As a start, I used only two predictors, being the "perc_opp" and "l_perc_opp". I thought to use the hat value, the diagonal of

$h_{i}=diag\big(X_i'(X'X)^{-1}X_i\big)$

But then I am just selecting values with a high leverage, being also values whose both predictors seems fine (selected points with high leverage in red):

[image]

How can I select just the points that are of the diagonal? And how do I do this in five dimension feature space?

Comment: If it's the off diagonal you wish to identify, try residual rather than leverage. But my worry is judging the validity of a data point based on the model derived by the same data set. You can't call something wrong just because it does not conform to your theoretical model, what if your model is wrong?

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like something a Bayesian would know how to handle.

Answer (score 1):

You can make 5 different pre-models with just 4 predictors. And then you can forecast the final result by some sort of average. You might calculate average from only 3 "middle" pre-forecasts throwing out the minimum and maximum forecasts - there probably would be your fifth contaminated predictor.

Comment: This sounds like the "mixture of experts" or "committee machine" problem so a committee machine approach might work.  You are using the ensemble - bootstrapping the model.

Comment: But is there no way to guess which predictor is the contaminated one without using the outcome variable?

Comment: @Kasper It depends on your data. If you use variables like height and weight than the answer is NO. Imagine you have a case of a heavy dwarf. How can you tell then that contaminated is either his weight or contaminated is his height? The forecast of pre-model which gives you most outlying forecast far away from the median of forecasts has the contaminated predictor.

Comment: Yes but what I am referring to is: I have 2 height measurements by two machines and 2 weight measurements by two machines. The 2 height measurements indicate we are dealing with a dwarf, and only one weight makes sense, the other weight is clearly not the one of a dwarf. How do I select the wrong weight as wrong measurement?

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough data to fit vector autoregression (VAR) model, you could use it to get the fitted values for each data point then measure how far is your predictor from it in terms of the error variance.